# Error while creating a TPU: "cannot be less than the existing policy version"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tpu

I am trying to create a TPU using GC console:

```
ctpu up --name=daniels-tpu --zone=us-central1-b --tpu-size=v3-8 --tf-version=1.15 --tpu-only -noconf --require-permissions
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
ctpu will use the following configuration:
  Name:                 daniels-tpu2
  Zone:                 us-central1-b
  GCP Project:          ai2-aristo
  TensorFlow Version:   1.15
  Cloud TPU:
      Size:             v3-8
      Preemptible:      false
      Reserved:         false
OK to create your Cloud TPU resources with the above configuration? [Yn]: y
2020/01/31 21:12:21 Creating TPU daniels-tpu2 (this may take a few minutes)...
2020/01/31 21:12:28 TPU operation still running...
2020/01/31 21:12:49 TPU operation still running...
2020/01/31 21:13:10 TPU operation still running...
2020/01/31 21:13:31 TPU operation still running...
2020/01/31 21:13:36 Created TPU daniels-tpu2!
2020/01/31 21:13:36 Error adding the TPU's service account to the project's access control lists: &googleapi.Error{Code:400, Message:"Requested policy version (1) cannot be less than the existing policy versi
on (3). For more information, please refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#versions.", Body:"{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"Requested policy version (1) cannot be less
 than the existing policy version (3). For more information, please refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#versions.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Requested policy versio
n (1) cannot be less than the existing policy version (3). For more information, please refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#versions.\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \
"badRequest\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n  }\n}\n", Header:http.Header(nil), Errors:[]googleapi.ErrorItem{googleapi.ErrorItem{Reason:"badRequest", Message:"Requested policy versio
n (1) cannot be less than the existing policy version (3). For more information, please refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#versions."}}}
googleapi: Error 400: Requested policy version (1) cannot be less than the existing policy version (3). For more information, please refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#versions., badRequest
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the TPU instance successfully with the same command. Have you tried using a different [zone](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/memcached/regions?hl=en#supported_regions)?
I also found a [thread](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5218) that I believe could be very useful.